# Solve for x: $\sqrt{x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}}$ + $\sqrt{x+8-6\sqrt{x-1}}$ = $1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do i solve this equation?

$\sqrt{x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}}$ + $\sqrt{x+8-6\sqrt{x-1}}$ = $1$.

i do not know how to start?

Thanks

Comment: As @Roman83 has solved the equation, note that $x$ has infinitely many real roots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Try to set $u=\sqrt{x-1}$, i.e. $x=u^2+1$ and see what you get. It simplifies very nicely...

Comment: Yes it simplifies nicely. But i am stuck at $|u-2|+|u-3|=1$

Comment: Let $f(u)=|u-2|+|u-3|$. Then for $2\leq u\leq 3$, you get $f(u)=(u-2)+(3-u)=1$ while if $u>3$: $f(u)=(u-2)+(u-3)=2u-5>1$ and with $u<2$: $f(u)=5-2u>1$. But better try to draw the graph of $f$.

Answer (score 5):

#### Hint:

$$\sqrt{x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}}=\sqrt{x-1-4\sqrt{x-1}+4}=$$
$$=\sqrt{(\sqrt{x-1}-2)^2}=|\sqrt{x-1}-2|$$

Then:

> $$\sqrt{x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{x+8-6\sqrt{x-1}} = 1$$
> $$\sqrt{x-1-4\sqrt{x-1}+4} + \sqrt{x-1-6\sqrt{x-1}+9} = 1$$
> $$\sqrt{(\sqrt{x-1}-2)^2}+\sqrt{(\sqrt{x-1}-3)^2}=1$$
> $$|\sqrt{x-1}-2|+|\sqrt{x-1}-3|=1$$
> $$2\le\sqrt{x-1}\le3$$
> $$5\le x \le 10$$

Comment: Can you explain from third last step to second last step? Thanks

Comment: If $\sqrt{x-1}=t$ then $$|t-2|+|t-3|=1$$
$$t\in[2;3]$$

Comment: This is exactly my dount again from second last step to last step in your comment. Can you elaborate on this? Thanks

Comment: OK. I will write later.